make vscode show error when importing commonjs module incorrectly
I have typescript repo with esm and type=module, so, no commonJS.
I need to import a commonJS package and I did something like:
import { aFunction } from 'someCommonJSPackage';

vscode is not complaining about this, but when I build and generate js from ts, then run the js generated it complains that I should do something like:
import someCommonJSPackage from 'someCommonJSPackage';
const { aFunction } = someCommonJSPackage;

How can I make vscode show the error? Some eslint rule I'm missing? Any tsconfig option I'm missing? My tsconfig file looks like:
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest", "node"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ES2021",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "es2021", "esnext.asyncIterable"],
  }
}

